# Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data to fetch json response from server side, my embeer model looks like.

```
App.Field = DS.Model.extend
  component: DS.attr 'string'
  fieldinfos: DS.hasMany('App.Fieldinfo')

App.Field.reopenClass
  forInstitution: (institution)->
    App.Field.find { institution_id: institution.id }
```

and my json response looks like

```
{
    :login_fields => [
        [0] {
                :component => "ns4:FieldInfoComponent",
                       :id => 1,
            :fieldinfo_ids => [
                [0] 1
            ]
        },
        [1] {
                :component => "ns4:FieldInfoComponent",
                       :id => 2,
            :fieldinfo_ids => [
                [0] 2
            ]
        },
        [2] {
                :component => "ns4:FieldInfoComponent",
                       :id => 3,
            :fieldinfo_ids => [
                [0] 3
            ]
        }
    ],
      :fieldinfos => [
        [0] {
            :field_info_obj => "FieldInfoSingle",
            :login_field_id => 1,
                        :id => 1,
               :element_ids => [
                [0] 1
            ]
        },
        [1] {
            :field_info_obj => "FieldInfoSingle",
            :login_field_id => 2,
                        :id => 2,
               :element_ids => [
                [0] 2
            ]
        },
        [2] {
            :field_info_obj => "FieldInfoSingle",
            :login_field_id => 3,
                        :id => 3,
               :element_ids => [
                [0] 3
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

it works perfectly when I call once 
App.Field.find { institution_id: 1 }

but in between if I again call for different institution
 App.Field.find { institution_id: 2 }

Following is the code that fetch loginfields whenever institution changes

```
loginFields: (->
    return [] unless @get('institution')?
    App.LoginField.forInstitution(@get 'institution')
  ).property 'institution'
```

It gives me  Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined error

what I am doing wrong over here and what I need to do to resolve this error. help!

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to find "Field" first and second time?

Comment: @Sushant I add the code that try to find fields, Please help!